# I am calling back to java from a c++ dll and CallVoidMethod causes an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. What am I missing

Tags: java-native-interface

Environment
C++ DLL created using Visual Studio 2017
Java program running under Intellij using its supplied Java environement

When I run the java application I get the std::cout messages up to the callback message
Then the system halts

When I attach the debugger in Visual Studio I get an access violation at address 0x0...0240

Something about the CallVoidMethod is incorrect but I am unsure what. So far I have been unable to find answers that apply to this simple case online.

Code

JAVA

```
public class Main {
    public native void executeNativeCode();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("JNITarget" );
    }
    // write your code here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().executeNativeCode();
        System.out.println("Java Done");
    }

    public void helloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello World from Java!");
    }


 }
```

C++

````
// JNITarget.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "jni.h"
#include "com_poc_Main.h"
#include "JNITarget.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_poc_Main_executeNativeCode(JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObj) {
    std::cout << "Hello World from C++!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Get java class object" << std::endl;
    jclass thisClass = env->GetObjectClass(thisObj);
    std::cout << "Get callback method" << std::endl;
    jmethodID callback = env->GetMethodID(thisClass, "helloWorld", "()V");
    std::cout << "Call callback method" << std::endl;
    env->CallVoidMethod(thisClass, callback);
    std::cout << "C++ done" << std::endl;

    return;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for anyone else who runs into this changing the CallVoidMethod arguments to

```
env->CallVoidMethod(thisObj, callback)
```

instead of

```
env->CallVoidMethod(thisClass, callback)
```

fixes the problem